# $C[0,1]$ is dense in $L^2[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

I would like to prove that $C[0,1]$ is dense in $L^2[0,1]$ without using measure theory, since I am yet to study measure and integration theory.

Let $f\in L^2[0,1]$. Let $\epsilon>0$. I want to prove that there is some $g\in C[0,1]$ such that $\parallel f-g \parallel <\epsilon$. I can use Minkowski's inequality to get $\parallel f-g \parallel_2 \le\parallel f \parallel_2+\parallel g \parallel_2$. I do not know how to proceed now.

Comment: How is $L^2[0,1]$ defined *without measure theory*?

Comment: You can probably use partial Fourrier sum

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio provisionally, one can define it to be the set of all functions defined in $[0,1]$ which are square-integrable (*a la* Riemann), I think.

Comment: @Simoes: I agree, the notation here might be confusing. We cannot really define $\mathcal{L}^2[0,1]$ without measure theory, but we are free to talk about square-integrable functions (with respect to the Riemann integral) over $[0,1]$. Such a space is not really $L^2[0,1]$, but clearly we may find good continuous approximations in the $L^2$-(semi)norm by truncating a Fourier series in both cases.

Comment: Can't we definite $L^2$ as metric completion of $C$ with $L^2$ norm? But then it is obviously dense...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may achieve the goal through the following steps: if $f\in L^2[0,1]$, $\,f$ can be expanded as a Fourier series:
$$ f(x)\stackrel{L_2}{=} M_0+\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(c_n \cos(2\pi n x)+ s_n\sin(2\pi n x)\right) \tag{1}$$
where
$$ \int_{0}^{1}f(x)^2\,dx = M_0^2 + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 1}(c_n^2+s_n^2)\tag{2} $$
is granted by Parseval's theorem. On the other hand
$$ f_N(x)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=} M_0+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(c_n \cos(2\pi n x)+ s_n\sin(2\pi n x)\right)\tag{3} $$
is a continuous function, and 
$$ \left\|f-f_N\right\|_2^2 = \int_{0}^{1}\left(f(x)-f_N(x)\right)^2\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n>N}(c_n^2+s_n^2)\tag{4} $$
goes to zero as $N\to +\infty$ by $(2)$. This proves that $C[0,1]$ is dense in $L^2[0,1]$, but have we really avoided measure theory? I do not think so, it is deeply rooted in $(2)$, essentially stating that $\mathcal{L}^2[0,1]\simeq \ell^2$.